# FK hand not displaying. I can only get the IK to work

Tags: animation, rigging

I am switching from Maya to Blender. I cannot get the FK (Forward Kinematics) to work. I am using the [Vincent rig](http://www.blendernation.com/2016/04/22/blender-cloud-vincent-model-rig/), the rig is showing, and I loaded in [BlenRig 5](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/). Is there a trick or tutorial? I don't even see the elbow joint. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to pose Vincent https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/#57443403c379cf17984528fa